# Solspace Calendar displaying a list of events and their individual occurrences

Tags: solspace, calendar

I need to display each calendar and the related events. The events are reoccurring and I want the dates and times for each occurrence to appear under the event title. To save my life I can't figure it out.  I don't have much experience with Calendar and I've already spend a crazy amount of time trying to figure this out.  It has to be simple but no luck.  Below is an example of what I'm needing to display.

## **Calendar Title**

### Event Title

Day and Time

Day and Time

### Event Title

Day and Time

Day and Time

Day and Time

## **Calendar Two Title**

### Event Title

Day and Time

Day and Time

Each event has various days and times throughout a given week and I want to avoid displaying the event name over and over.  I just need it to display cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

> **VERY recommended initial reading** on Calendar tag use: https://solspace.com/docs/calendar/getting_started/

If you're looking to display an event, then display all its occurrences, then move to the next event, display all its occurrences, etc, then you should try `{exp:calendar:events}` with either `{occurrences}...{/occurrences}` or `{exp:calendar:occurrences}...{/exp:calendar:occurrences}` inside the `{exp:calendar:events}` tag pair. Eg.

```
{exp:calendar:events /* your parameters */}
    <h2>{event_title}</h2>
    <p>This event happens on these days</p>
    {occurrences}
       {!-- Could use {exp:calendar:occurrences} as an alternative --}
       ... your occurrence code ...
    {/occurrences}
{/exp:calendar:events /* your parameters */}
```

> **Keep in mind that this does not create a chronological list of events**, since occurrences will be listed one event after another, and therefore will not overlap if they overlap over time. [See the above link (and image)](https://solspace.com/docs/calendar/getting_started/) for some more detailed explanations why.

If you're looking for a **chronological listing of event occurrences**, in which event occurrences for each day, or on a specified day, are displayed chronologically, use `{exp:calendar:cal}`. This is the tag to use if you're looking for occurrences within a specific time frame. Eg.

```
<h2>Event occurrences on August 3rd, 2015</h2>
{exp:calendar:cal 
   date_range_start="2015-08-03"
   date_range_end="2015-08-03"
   pad_short_weeks="n"}
    {event_title}: {event_start_date format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"} ~ {event_end_date format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%i"}<br />
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfect!  I'm not sure what I was doing wrong before but this worked. Thought I had tried it but apparently without success. I read the documentation early on but evidently I had poor implementation. Thanks for the help. My issue was fixed within minutes.

Comment: Could please convert this to a comment on an answer or the original question? This **is not** an answer.

Comment: Also, please **accept** @Solspace's answer if it answered your question.